# Speckle Noise Generation

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

Sorry if this seems like a silly or lazy "I-can't-find-it' question but I've been trying for a few days now to find a paper or anything of the like to explain how to generate speckle noise (on 2D images). I have found out that one of the more simple means of removing speckle noise is a mean filter (which I've already implemented) but absolutely nowhere can I find a way of generating the noise. Could someone please direct me to where I can learn to generate speckle noise? Furthermore would it be a stretch to ask if there was a simple way to do it in OpenCV (a C++ image processing library).

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Speckle noise is essentially a multiplicative noise, which may (or may not) have an additive noise as well (definitions vary depending upon circumstances). This [paper](http://www.csio.res.in:8085/ncci/ICCIpdfDoc/spackle%20noise.pdf) provides a good overview of speckle noise, including descriptions and approaches to removing it.

Here is a some simple python code that can produce multiplicative speckle noise:

```
import cv

im = cv.LoadImage('tree.jpg', cv.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
mult_noise = cv.CreateImage((im.width,im.height), cv.IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1)

cv.RandArr(cv.RNG(6), mult_noise, cv.CV_RAND_NORMAL, 1, 0.1)    

cv.Mul(im, mult_noise, im)

cv.ShowImage("tree with speckle noise", im)
cv.WaitKey(0)
```

no noise:

[image]

with speckle noise:
[image]

Comment: Wow! Code + excellent explanation + a paper I can reference? Thank you so much.

Comment: The link in your answer is dead.

Answer (score 0):

Speckle noise is linked to the physical imaging process, so I'm not sure it's easy (or even really possible) to simulate it in a general manner.

However, depending on your desired type of images, you can use other forms of noise to approach it. I guess that a multiplicative salt-and-pepper noise should more or less do the trick for simularing a SAR image.

Another (probably better) possibility is to explore the websites of NASA / ESA and look for SAR images (look for programs like Pleiades, Cosmo-Skymed  and SAR Lupe). Some gated laser imaging labs have mnybe also released publicly some sample data.

Comment: I have developed methods to generate S&P noise so if I just multiply the a S&P result with that of the input it should be "similar" to Speckle noise? My application is actually to compare and contrast the denioseing ability of the different spatial, frequency and wavelet techniques. The problem with that is that I am asked to corrupt images using a) Gaussian b) S&P and c) Speckle. I have developed methods previously for the other two but seem to bit stuck on the speckle images. I'll also take a look into the other possibility. Thanks for the quick reply :)

Comment: Is it for a scientific image processing course ? Most of the basic courses assume speckle as a multiplicative noise, so multiplying your image with the noise (instead of adding it) should do the trick. But you can ask confirmation to the TA.

Answer (score 0):

It can be just a matter of adding gaussian noise to your image. [`cvRandArr`](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html#randarr) seems like a good candidate.

You can also have something more sophisticated by pondering your noise with your signal, which is also easy since it's just some pixel-wide multiplication between original image and your noise.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply. As I've mentioned elsewhere my application requires that I generate noise for Gaussian, Salt & Pepper and Speckle.

Comment: "speckle" is a generic denomination for noisy pattern, it can be gaussian or S&P, so I don't get what's asked

Comment: Speckle is multiplicative, adding Gaussian noise by definition is not speckle.